# jquery plugin global variable (function(winkstart, amplify, undefined) {

Tags: jquery, plugins

i was working on jquery project and having some doubt. i was checking one js file code file name was winkstart.js and also having some its corrusponding files like winkstart-request.js, winkstart-util.js.
In every file and almost in all files they have used same code like given below.
below we have two line first and last line of file. so i am in doubt what exact we are doing with winkstart amplify and undefined here. and what about last line code .

```
(function(winkstart, amplify, undefined) {

// Statement

})( window.winkstart = window.winkstart || {}, window.amplify = window.amplify || {});
```

i have seen code for jquery plugin like

```
(function($){
# statement
})(jQuery);
```

as its self executed function but why we are using winkstart and amplify . are these variable we are passing in plugins like global variable or something we are passing other jquery plugins variable in this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing those global variables so that there won't be any ambiguity between the global and local variables. As far `undefined` is concerned, it is redundant I suppose, and there is no need of assigning  twice.

The above answer, still depends on how the body is implemented.